# UIView has no events

Tags: cocoa, events, uiview, interface-builder

I want to be able to connect the touchUp event of my UIView to an IBAction, but I can't see any events. I thought that there was a subclass of UIView that did have actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you aren't looking for the events on [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?  That is a subclass of UIView.